# Extending properties for qtip or other selector plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, properties, extend, qtip

I am trying to set bunch of default properties for multiple instances of qtip, but it is not working. is it possible or am I doing something wrong?

Common Properties

```
    var qtipDefaults = {
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout',
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'bottomLeft',
                tooltip: 'topLeft'
            }
        },
        style: {
            name: 'dark'
        }
    };
```

Instantiation # 1

```
    $('#sbt_name').qtip({
        content: 'This is the Name of the Course'
    }).extend(qtipDefaults);
```

Instantiation # 2

```
    var sbt_name = $('#sbt_name').qtip({
        content: 'This is the Name of the Course'
    });
    $.extend(sbt_name, qtipDefaults);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must prepare qtip parameters before calling qtip plugin. Try this:

```
$('#sbt_name').qtip($.extend(true, {}, qtipDefaults, {
    content: 'This is the Name of the Course'
}));
```

`$.extend()` merges two or more objects. `true` parameter indicates it will make deep copy. First object is empty, for keeping original qtipDefaults unchanged.

Comment: This did the trick in my case. I wanted to pass only `my` and `at` properties that go inside the `position` array. Thanks for the explanation.